# How can I make a KinematicBody2D rotate based on it's y velocity while falling through the air?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am attempting to recreate Geometry Dash in Godot Engine. I am using version 3.5.1.stable.

I have successfully made the cube rotate when jumping by setting it's rotation degrees property to be velocity.y divided by 5, but have not been able to apply the same logic for the KinematicBody2D when it's falling.

I have tried checking for the velocity on the way down from the apex, and setting that as an indicator for the body falling down, but it doesn't work at all, the cube does not rotate.

I'm having trouble explaining the many different ways I have tried to solve this, but if someone asks I will try my best to answer.

This is for my school project in game development, and this little issue has been stalling the entire process.

If anyone can provide some logic or insight on how I can fix this issue, that would be great, thanks!

Comment: Is the problem detecting if the body is falling, or is the problem making it rotate once you know it is falling?

Comment: The problem is making it rotate. I am able to make it rotate while falling, but it introduces an even greater problem where the KinematicBody2D jitters quickly back and forth due to the velocity mysteriously getting set to 25 for a single frame at the start of the game, before being set back to 0. With the logic in the code, this leads to the velocity changing from 25 to 0, 0 to 25 (which I believe has something to do with the gravity being applied), which based on how the cube rotates (rotation is dependent on the y velocity), leads to jittering.

Comment: Isn't the rotation jittering because the detection of the body falling is jittering? Anyway, without the details of what is going on, I can still suggest you: 1. Use the time since it was last not falling (you might be familiar with coyote time, same idea). 2. Ease the rotation so it does not have big changes one frame to the next.